# how to pass image source to <a> and <img> on closing a modal window?

Tags: jquery

I've a page in which I've below code:

```
<div id="img-wrap">
<a href="images/BIGGEST.JPG" class="MYCLASS" title="MYTITLE">  
    <img src="images/SMALL.JPG" title="IMAGE TITLE">  
</a>
</div>
```

(say the images are 001-t.jpg for SMALL.jpg, 001.jpg for BIGGER.jpg, 001-b.jpg for BIGGEST.jpg)

on the same page I've a modal window which is having a BIGGER.jpg version of the same image.

```
<div id="mainImage">
    <img src="images/BIGGER.JPG" /> 
</div>
```

Now what i would like to achieve on closing the modal window is... if the modal window has 002.jpg on closing the

```
<a href="images/BIGGEST.JPG" />
```

should be

```
<a href="images/002-b.JPG" />
```

and

```
<img src="images/SMALL.JPG" />
```

should be

```
<img src="images/002.JPG" />
```

say on the modal window the image changes dynamically. Any help is greatly appreciated. THanks!!

What I'm tried is:

```
$('.window .close, #mask').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $('#mask,.window').hide();
        var currentSelection = $("#mainImage").attr("src");
        $(".MYCLASS img").attr("src",currentSelection);
        //alert(currentSelection);
        //var newHref = "images/";
        $('a.MYCLASS').attr("href",currentSelection); 
    });
```

but which is not working

Answer (score 2):

On the `.click()` function, which activates the modal window, you can get the parameters from the `<a href="" ...><img src="" ... /></a>` tag and modify the modal window right?

For example, you have an image like this:

```
<a href="images/myimage-big.jpg" class="modal" title="My Image">
    <img src="images/myimage-small.jpg" title="My Image">
</a>
```

And, the `.click()` function can be this way:

```
$(".modal").click(function(){
    var imageUrl = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".window img").attr("src", imageUrl);
    $('#mask,.window').fadeIn();
});
```